# Why is the second-order (covariant) derivative of metric tensor NOT zero while the first-order is?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

[image]

If the first-order differentiation has given off zero, wouldn't the second-order be the result of differentiating *that* ZERO, just leading to zero?

Comment: This notation is poor and therefore confusing you. The left side of each equation is being evaluated at only one point $P$. Eq. (6.5) says only that the first derivatives vanish *at* $P$. (By the way, these are just partial derivatives, not covariant derivatives.)

Comment: Consider $y = x^2$, so $dy/dx = 2x$ and $d^2y/dx^2 = 2$. At the point $x=0$ the first derivative is zero but the second is not.

Comment: Are you using Ray D'Inverno's text? I usually think highly of it, but this missing explanation is a clear minus point...

Comment: Thank you, guys. It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your definitions above, it appears that you are in the special case of a metric that is transformed into Reimann Normal Coordinates.  And the point there is that, at a point, you can always diagonalize the matrix by switching to an eigenvector basis, and then rescaling the new coordinates by the eigenvalues to reduce the metric to the minkowski metric.  Then, find the geodesics along your new basis vectors, and take them to be the coordinate basis of your new neighborhood.  By the definition of geodesics, vectors parallel translate along geodesics, and the first derivatives of the metric vanish.

As for the second derivatives, they cannot be made to all vanish by any coordinate transformation, because the curvature tensors are tensors, and depend explicitly on second derivatives of the metric, which, if it is nonzero at a point, must be nonzero in every coordinate system

Comment: Thank you. By "curvature tensor", you'd mean something like Riemann curvature tensor, wouldn't you?

And may I ask you where I can study the quantitative examples of such eingenvector bases that you mentioned?

Comment: @MinnHtutkyaw: yes, I mean the Riemann curvature tensor.  And you can look for "Riemann normal coordinates" in the index of any GR book, or google for them, and there will be any number of sources.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Schirmer.